# Is it true that JFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation() default value is HIDE_ON_CLOSE?

Tags: java, swing, jframe

I know it is said in the document that `JFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(int)` is `HIDE_ON_CLOSE`. But when I press the `X` on current frame window, not only does it hide the current frame but also terminate the running program. Can anyone explain?

**Edit:** The closing frame is not the last frame left.

Comment: From the [Java Docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/javax/swing/JFrame.html#getDefaultCloseOperation()) `The default behavior is to simply hide the JFrame when the user closes the window` - so, yes

Comment: *",not only it hide the current frame but also terminate the running program. Can anyone explain"* - Yes.  The Event Dispatching Thread will terminate when the last window is closed.  This then allows the JVM to terminate - this is expected behaviour and a good way to determine when you app might not be operating properly (ie leaving non-daemon threads laying around)

Comment: *The Event Dispatching Thread will terminate when the last window is closed.* - on Windows the JVM does not terminate. However, the frame Icon disappears from the task bar, so there is no way to reactivate the frame that I know of. So I'm not sure when you would ever use this setting. Generally in an application you should only have a single JFrame, then for child windows you would use a JDialog. *The closing frame is not the last frame left.* - post your [mre] demonstrating the problem is you still have a problem when using a JDialog.

Comment: *Is this a problem with my machine or they just made some changed with the JVM/IDE* - or maybe you have a coding problem? Unless we can test the code we can't answer that question. That is why a [mre] should be posted with every question!!!

Answer (score 2):

> Is it true that `JFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation()` default value is `HIDE_ON_CLOSE`?

Run this method on the frame.

```
public static void showDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame frame) {
    final int closeOp = frame.getDefaultCloseOperation();
    switch (closeOp) {
        case JFrame.DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE:
            System.out.println("DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE");
            break;
        case JFrame.HIDE_ON_CLOSE:
            System.out.println("HIDE_ON_CLOSE");
            break;
        case JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE:
            System.out.println("EXIT_ON_CLOSE");
            break;
        case JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE:
            System.out.println("DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE");
            break;
        default:
            System.err.println("Not found: " + closeOp);
    }
}
```

Here it prints:

```
HIDE_ON_CLOSE
```

So the answer to that is: yes, it is true.

Here at least. What result do you get on the local machine / environment?

Comment: I got `EXIT_ON_CLOSE` instead.That was unexpected.Is this a problem with my machine or they just made some changed with the JVM/IDE.I'm using Netbeans 8.2 and Java 1.8.0_211

Comment: *"That was unexpected."* There's an easy fix for that: don't *expect* a close operation, but instead ***set a close operation.*** I prefer `DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE` except for rare instances when none of the default close operations quite fits, and implement a [`WindowListener`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.desktop/java/awt/event/WindowListener.html) with `DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE`.